# How to make threaded animation faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram every 100ms.

The data of histogram is generated by a thread in parallel and stored in global variable

For histogram , if bins=255 the animation slows down

I need some way to make it faster

This my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random
import time
import threading

mutex = threading.RLock()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
y = 0


def animate(i):
    global y
    mutex.acquire()
    data = y
    mutex.release()
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.hist(data, bins=255)


def data_collect_worker(nsize):
    global y
    y2 = []
    while True:
        y2 = [random.randint(0, 255) for i in range(int(nsize))]
        mutex.acquire()
        y = y2
        mutex.release()
        time.sleep(0.01)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = threading.Thread(target=data_collect_worker, args=(255,))
    x.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    animate(1)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: "I am trying to plot a histogram every 100ms.", `FuncAnimation(..., interval=10)`. You're also sleeping, which I'm not sure if it's just a placeholder for something else that's taking time.

Comment: did you see https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/histogram.html this runs at 60fps with 300 bins for me.  it is structured very differently and suggests that the reason it's slow for you is because you're using it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Due to Python's [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) (Global Interpreter Lock) nothing is actually happening in parallel here. If you want true concurrency you will have to ditch `threading` in favor of `multiprocessing`.

Comment: pretty sure this isn't anything to do with Python's GIL!  why would you say this is the case?

Comment: @SamMason 
"The data of histogram is generated by a thread in parallel"
"I need some way to make it faster"
Since it's not actually in parallel and I don't see any IO bound operations here, using `threading` will decrease performance, while using `multiprocessing` will speed things up substantially.